# Sum by window function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I`m trying to count sum by window function of PostgresQL.

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES
('2012-06-21 05:20:00',12),
('2012-06-21 05:21:00',14),
('2012-06-21 05:22:00',10),
('2012-06-21 05:23:00',20),
('2012-06-21 05:24:00',25),
('2012-06-21 05:25:00',30),
('2012-06-21 05:26:00',10);

SELECT dt,
cnt,
sum(cnt) OVER (order by dt ROWS BETWEEN 3 preceding AND 0 preceding)
FROM t
ORDER BY dt;
```

I want to count for each 3 rows and expect to get such a result and i get this

```
2012-06-21 05:21:00 14  26
2012-06-21 05:22:00 10  36
2012-06-21 05:23:00 20  56
2012-06-21 05:24:00 25  69
2012-06-21 05:25:00 30  85
2012-06-21 05:26:00 10  85
```

Tell me, please, it is possible to get result like

```
2012-06-21 05:20:00 12  0
2012-06-21 05:21:00 14  0
2012-06-21 05:22:00 10  36
2012-06-21 05:23:00 20  0
2012-06-21 05:24:00 25  0
2012-06-21 05:25:00 30  75
2012-06-21 05:26:00 10  0
```

by window function? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional logic:

```
SELECT dt, cnt,
       (case when row_number() over (order by dt) % 3 = 0
             then sum(cnt) OVER (order by dt ROWS BETWEEN 3 preceding AND 0 preceding)
        else 0
       end)
FROM t
ORDER BY dt;
```

Comment: @gordon-linoff, dont need to use the between, only " ROWS 3 preceding " can do the job.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2c11deb0e6572b9f7f90106311781012

Comment: @Frederic . . . I am aware of that shortcut.  I prefer to be explicit about window frames.